# What would be a natural way to say "to milk it for all it's worth"?

Tags: idioms

As an example,

A is making a speech:

> "..yes, you can simulate a hurricane in a computer but does the computer really feel wetness?"

Me:

> "Wow, going forward I am going to milk this analogy for all it's worth"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to express that is:

取れるだけ取っとけ

meaning, loosely, "take as much as can be taken".

In your particular example (milking an analogy), though, the relevant action is *USE* (i.e., to use something as much as you can). In that case, you could go with:

使い倒そう

with 使い倒す meaning "to use every bit of / get the most out of".